# How to delete rows in RecycleView in one go?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a student and fresher to android development.

After a lot of research, I have successfully implemented RecycleView for my project. In my project when the user long clicks on the row in RecyclerView he gets a checkbox and a delete button for all rows which he can use to delete the row. But what I want is that when the user long clicks on any row. Only that row's particular checkbox or delete button should become visible. And to select other rows he can click on them and they will become selected and then have global delete button which can delete any rows the user has selected. Any suggestions or blog where I can look?
**MyCustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomRecyclerViewHolder>{

    List<RecyclerViewClass> mItems;
    Context mContext;
    boolean onLongPressReceived = false;
    UpdateMainClass updateMainClass;

    /**
     * Contructor to initialize context and list items.
     * @param context Context of the Activity on which RecyclerView is initialised
     * @param items List of POJO object that contains the data to update the rows
     */
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RecyclerViewClass> items){
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
        //Check whether the Activity implements UpdateMainClass Interface or not
        if(context instanceof UpdateMainClass){
            updateMainClass = (UpdateMainClass)context;
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>This method updates the long press status variable when called from the Activity</p>
     * <p>Helpful to prevent any unwanted changes to status variable</p>
     * @param status tell whether whether long press is clicked or not
     */
    public void setOnLongPressStatus(boolean status){
        onLongPressReceived = status;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Provides the long press status to the Activity
     * @return longPressReceived status
     */
    public boolean getLongPressStatus(){
        return onLongPressReceived;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_recyclerview_layout, parent, false);
        //set the margin if any, will be discussed in next blog
        return new CustomRecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mAvatarView.setImageDrawable(mItems.get(position).getmImage_url());
        holder.mMsg1.setText(mItems.get(position).getMessage1());
        holder.mMsg2.setText(mItems.get(position).getMessage2());
        /**
         * <p>Enable the row delete and select layout and
         * Colors the background based on check box status if onLongPressReceived variable is set to true</p>
         * <p>Otherwise renders a regular white background list with visible checkboxes that are selected.</p>
         */
        if(onLongPressReceived) {
            holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mItems.get(position).getmIsChecked());
            holder.mDeleteRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(mItems.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmIsChecked()){
                holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_selected));
            }else {
                //holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_long_pressed));
            }
        }
            //Checking whether a particular view is clicked or not
        else{
            holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_unselected));
            holder.mDeleteRow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (mItems.get(position).getmIsChecked()) {
                holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        //Calls the interface method in Activity to respond to CheckBox changes
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                System.out.println("Holder Position is:   " + holder.getAdapterPosition());
                System.out.println("Holder Boolean is  " + b);
                updateMainClass.updateListBackground(holder.getAdapterPosition(), b);
            }
        });
        /**
         * <p>Responds to long press made on any row</p>
         * <p>Checks the item on which long press is made
         * sets the onLongPressReceived status to true and notify the adapter to refresh the list.</p>
         */
        holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                onLongPressReceived = true;
                mItems.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setmIsChecked(true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
        //Calls the interface in Activity to remove the item from the List.
        holder.mDeleteRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                updateMainClass.updateItemList(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public class CustomRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView mMsg1, mMsg2;
        private ImageView mAvatarView;
        private CheckBox mCheckBox;
        private LinearLayout checkboxHolder;
        private ImageView mDeleteRow;
        private CardView cardView;


        /**
         * Initializes all the views of a ViewHolder
         * @param itemView parent view in which all the List Item views are present
         */
        public CustomRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mMsg1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
            mMsg2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
            mAvatarView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar_holder);
            mCheckBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            checkboxHolder = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_holder);
            mDeleteRow = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_row);
            cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_holder);
        }
    }
    public interface UpdateMainClass{
        void updateItemList(int position);
        void updateListBackground(int position, boolean isChecked);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the selected rows from the Adapter's list (mItems) and then call notifyItemChanged(position) or notifyItemRangeChanged() ? Notice that the RecyclerView reflect the state of the items that in the list you subscribed in the adapter. when you change the state of an item, notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyItemChange() must be called in order to reflect the new state/changes made.

Comment: I will look into that. Also, when I click on a particular row. I only want to see the check box of that particular row and not of the whole list. Any idea how to do implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your adapter from [this](https://gist.github.com/raviteja83/1628a6f58fc2563209da0e9472a4cc3b) class. Then after long click on one view select that view and toggle the selected view after single click like this.
boolean longClicked = false;

```
@Override
public void OnItemClickListener(View v,int position){
   if(longClicked){ 
      mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
      return;
   }
  //normal click functionality here
}

@Override
public boolean OnItemLongClick(View v,int position){
   longClicked = true;
   mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
}
```

After selecting all the items to be deleted you can get the selected positions from the adapter as `mAdapter.getSelectedItems()`

**Note:**

Also don't forget to reset `longClicked` to `false` after your operation on selectedItems is completed.